# SSMS - Join 3 select statements referencing the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join 3 select statements that reference the same table.

The conditions of each select statement vary slightly.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

These queries work:

```
select [Account Name], sum(amount)as Amount from [dbo].[fmdr_1.19] 
where datepart(month,Period)=3
group by [Account Name], datepart(month,Period), [Account Name]


select [Account Name], sum(amount)as Q2 from [dbo].[fmdr_1.19] 
where datepart(month,Period)=6
group by [Account Name]


select [Account Name], sum(amount)as Q3 from [dbo].[fmdr_1.19] 
where datepart(month,Period)=9
group by [Account Name]
```

I'm trying to join each of these three select statements into 1 table.  When I run the following code, the error I'm getting is:

'Column 'T1.Q1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

I think I must not be far off.  I'm sure there is a more efficient way of achieving the same result, but I'm also trying to improve my capacity for Joining tables.

Thanks!

```
Select N0.[Account Name], T1.Q1, T2.Q2, T3.Q3 from [dbo].[fmdr_1.19] N0
join 
    (select [Account Name], sum(amount) as Q1 from [dbo].[fmdr_1.19] 
        where datepart(month,Period)=3
            group by [Account Name]) T1
        on T1.[Account Name] = N0.[Account Name]
join
    (select [Account Name], sum(amount)as Q2 from [dbo].[fmdr_1.19] 
        where datepart(month,Period)=6
            group by [Account Name]) T2
        on T2.[Account Name] = N0.[Account Name]
join
    (select [Account Name], sum(amount)as Q3 from [dbo].[fmdr_1.19] 
        where datepart(month,Period)=9
            group by [Account Name]) T3
        on T3.[Account Name]=N0.[Account Name]
group by N0.[Account Name]
```

Comment: when u use group by , you should include all columns from the select list unless an aggregate function is used or take off group by in the last part of query

Comment: Select N0.[Account Name], sum(T1.Q1) Q1,SUM( T2.Q2) Q2,SUM( T3.Q3) Q3 from ....... should work

Comment: @BHouse Thanks!  adding the other components of the Select list to the Group By clasue fixed the problem.

Comment: @AdMac If the problem is fixed now, please consider delete the question as no longer relevant.

Comment: i think it wont make any difference by adding other components to group by to taking off group by, because you haven't used any aggregate

Comment: For the record you don't need any joins if you want your query to run faster (and you'll have less code): SELECT Select N0.[Account Name], Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(month,N0.Period)=3 THEN N0.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Q1, Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(month,N0.Period)=6 THEN N0.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Q2, Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(month,N0.Period)=6 THEN N0.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Q3 from [dbo].[fmdr_1.19] AS N0 GROUP BY N0.[Account Name]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be more efficient:

```
SELECT SUM(t1_q1) AS Q1, SUM(t2_q2) AS Q2, SUM(t3_q3) AS Q3
FROM
(SELECT 
    CASE WHEN datepart(month,Period)=3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS t1_q1,
    CASE WHEN datepart(month,Period)=6 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS t2_q2,
    CASE WHEN datepart(month,Period)=9 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS t3_q3
FROM [dbo].[fmdr_1.19]
GROUP BY [Account Name]) AS grouped_tbl
```